# What do you call this type of class declaration?

Tags: python

I was looking at the [Faust docs](https://faust.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and I came across syntax for defining class templates (value objects?) in Python that I'd never seen before, and I cannot find any reference to them anywhere I look.

The syntax is:

```
class Order(faust.Record):
    account_id: str
    amount: int
```

I really enjoy its simplicity and declarative typing, but I cannot find any documentation on it. Can you help?

Comment: These are type annotations / type hints

Comment: this seems kinda similar to dataclasses, which are also great

Comment: The built-in [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) work similarly.